# paypal express checkout on mobile - checkout out as guest option

Tags: php, paypal

I have a paypal express checkout configuration working fine on desktop browsers and it offers both options 'log in with paypal' or 'checkout as guest' but on mobile it does not allow the user to pay via card directly with 'checkout as guest' - it always displays 'create an account' instead which is quite annoying does anyone know how to get the second option 'checkout as guest' showing up on mobiles?

Comment: Hey Robert, is this a mobile optimized solution or are you using REST apis?

Comment: It was just the new paypal express out of the box. With 'paypal standard' it will offer both choices: 'set up account' or 'check out as guest' by default on mobile as well as desktop. This would be the desired functionality with paypal express also; but for some reason on mobile, paypal express only offers 'set up account' - no 'check out as guest' option - is there a way? Else the original paypal is probably the better choice.

Comment: @RobertSheppard have you found a solution for this?

Comment: weird suggestion, but have you actually asked paypal?

Comment: can you attach some screen shots if it's still the case - it should really never happen that something is seen on desktop and not on mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, PayPal will render all buttons it finds eligible. However, some of their integrations allow to override this. PayPal calls these [funding sources](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/#link-funding). This [example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/standalone-buttons/#link-renderbuttons) demonstrates how you can customize what funding sources will be available.

```
// Loop over each funding source/payment method
paypal.getFundingSources().forEach(function (fundingSource) {
  // Initialize the buttons
  var button = paypal.Buttons({
    fundingSource: fundingSource,
  })
  // Check if the button is eligible
  if (button.isEligible()) {
    // Render the standalone button for that funding source
    button.render('#paypal-button-container')
  }
})
```